# jQuery - AJAX | Two ajax post on same page | After-POST problem/question

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm stack on a strange situation.
And I can't resolve it logically.

The problem:
(all have to be done without page refresh!):

- jQuery makes an AJAX POST to the server to add a content to the database.
  (Write something.)...(and it works!)
- Now that element is displayed (and have a delete button)
- Now if I click on THIS element to delete it (making a new jQuery AJAX POST)...
- nothing happens

Is AJAX that have restrictions or I have to check/re-edit/learn something?

Firebug returns that new element, and inspecting it - I should be able to delete it as I created it. (The delete works only after I make a page-refresh.)

Please help!

**EDIT.1:** LINK DELETED.

**EDIT.2:** here is the old (errata) code:
(The all is in 'document ready' function)

////////////COMMON:
    $('.list >*').addClass('delete');
     var valDel = 0; $('.delete').attr('value', function() {valDel++;    return +valDel;});

```
/////////////// WRITE:

$(function() {
    $("form.form #submit_btn").click(function() {

    //SOMETHING ON CLICK....+

        var name = $('#name').val();  
        var comment = $('#comment').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();

        var i = 0;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "ime="+ime+"&komentar="+komentar+"&email="+email,
        cache: false,
        success: function(){

        //SOMETHING ON SUCCESS....+

            $('.list >*').addClass('delete');
            $('.delete').attr('value', function() {i++;    return ''+i;}); // FIX: add again incremented values

        }
    });
    return false;
    });
}); 
/////////////////////// DELETE:


$(function() {
    $(".delete").click(function() {    // THE FIX: ...).live('click', function(){...
        $(this).addClass('toBeDeleted');
        var valx = $(this).attr("value");
        var string = 'valx='+ valx;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: string,
            cache: false,
            success: function(){

            $('.toBeDeleted').hide( function() { 
                $(this).remove();
                var reValDel = 0;$('.list >*').attr('value', function() {reValDel++;    return +reValDel;});
            });

          }
         });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Show a narrowed down version of your code illustrating and allowing us to reproduce the problem instead of a link to some site. Do you really expect someone reverse engineering your site to find your errors? I wouldn't.

Comment: You could use network panel in firebug to debug this on your own

Comment: @Darin: I appreciate your critics Darin, I'm fine enough with my codes, I wanted to give an idea, not rev-engineering the 'view source' 'cause it's almost impossible ;) I promise to post my codes soon after a solution as a reply. ||| Thanks @soju I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that when you dynamically add the dom elements after you create a new item, the click event handlers are not added. You should use the jQuery 'live' feature to bind click events to the elements.

Looking through your source it looks like you should change this:

```
$(".delete").click(function() {...
```

to this

```
$(".delete").live("click", function() {...
```

Comment: Nice idea! I'm right on my way for the changes! Thanks! I'll make you know

Comment: That was it! Giving a .live 'click' function resolved the problem! Now delete  works right after POSTing without refresh! Thanks rcravens!

Answer (score 1):

How are you binding the click event to the button? If you are not using the jquery live function you will need to rebind the click event. A live event will bind the click handler to all existing and future elements on a page. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Great solution! .live is the answer! I've tested it! now it's alive and waiting :D great!

Answer (score 1):

I can see from your code, you are calling `$(".delete").click(function() {...});` only once. When you use a selector like `$(".delete")` you are getting a collection of matching objects. If you add a new matching object you must run `$(".delete").click(function() {...});` again to update the collection of object to which you are binding a `click()` event... or you can listen to everyone else and use `.live()`

[jQuery live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

> This method is a variation on the
>   basic .bind() method for attaching
>   event handlers to elements. When
>   .bind() is called, the elements that
>   the jQuery object refers to get the
>   handler attached; elements that get
>   introduced later do not, so they would
>   require another .bind() call. For
>   instance, consider the HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="clickme">
    Click here
  </div>
</body>
```

> To bind a simple click handler to this
>   element:

```
$('.clickme').bind('click', function() {
  // Bound handler called.
});
```

> When the element is clicked, the
>   handler is called. However, suppose
>   that after this, another element is
>   added:

```
$('body').append('<div class="clickme">Another target</div>');
```

> This new element also matches the
>   selector .clickme, but since it was
>   added after the call to .bind(),
>   clicks on it will do nothing.
>
> The .live() method provides an
>   alternative to this behavior. To bind
>   a click handler to the target element
>   using this method:

```
$('.clickme').live('click', function() {
  // Live handler called.
});
```

> And then later add a new element:

```
$('body').append('<div class="clickme">Another target</div>');
```

> Then clicks on the new element will also trigger the handler.
>
> To unbind the click handlers from all  that were bound using .live(), use the .die() method:

```
$('.clickme').die('click');
```

Comment: WOW! I'll give you an UP vote! (or 10, only if I could). Thanks for this great explanations!

Comment: I cant take credit for anything but the first paragraph. The rest is from the link. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.live()` or `.delegate()` to achieve the desired effect. [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is a very awesome way to handle this sort of thing since it reduces the active number of event listeners on the page.

Comment: Great info Gabriel! Never heard abt. '.delegate' !!! I'll research it! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to use a `.click()` function on an element that has just been added to the DOM via your first Ajax call?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for a reply! I used the @rcravens solution .live. Now works great! Is active and waiting :D